# how many bridge hands have a singleton(one card) spade and exactly two doubleton suits(two cards of each suit)

Tags: combinations

What I would do is:C(13,1)C(13,2)C(3,1)C(13,2)C(2,1)C(13,8)C(1,1).But I don't know if I need to choose specific suits for the doubleton cards and the remaining 8 cards.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One spade card: 13 possibilities

Which doubleton suits: 3 possibilities: Which do we leave out?

Per doubleton suit there are C(13,2) = 78 possibilities.

For the remaining cards there are C(13,8) possibilities.

This gives a total of 39C(13,2)^2C(13,8).

This isn't the same as your answer: your answer is twice as large. This is beacuse you count the two doubleton suits as different.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by" doubleton suits: 3 possibilities".And why we need to multiply by 39 in the answer?

Comment: You can have clubs and hearts doubleton suits, clubs and diamonds doubleton suits or hearts and diamonds doubleton suits.

Comment: Oh,but does it influence the final results?

Comment: You count clubs+diamonds and diamonds+clubs as two different possibilities, while they are equal. (and the same for the other suits)

Comment: Why you choose the spade from 39?

Comment: I don't, the 39 is 3*13. Read the answer carefully please.